# Are low pressure (LP) compressors and booster compressors the same thing?

Tags: engine, turbofan, compressor

[image: v2500]

Based on the above picture, are "LP compressor" and "Booster compressor" different names for the same thing or are they actually different things?

Answer (score 1):

The same. LP (low pressure) compressors in turbines are sometimes referred to as booster compressors.